# How to find local this instead of global this?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am very new to React Native and the whole flow of such apps, so sorry if this is an obvious thing. :-)

Okay, so I have created a component that has this code within it:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {isLoading: true}; //this = object
}

componentWillMount() {
  var currentBusiness = firebase.database().ref("business/" + this.props.business)
  currentBusiness.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    currentBusinessData = snapshot.val()
    this.setState = ({isLoading: false}) //this = globalobject
  });
}
```

In my render function, I then want to use `this.state.isLoading` to trigger a new view when the data is loaded, however, the problem is in the function that is called, when data is returned, this refers to a ***globalobject***, which I assume is because the `firebase.database` is initiated on the global level, but how do I then call `setState` at the local component level, so that a new render is triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer this approach

```
currentBusiness.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    currentBusinessData = snapshot.val()
    this.setState({isLoading: false}) 
});
```

The arrow function gets the right 'this' for you.

Alternatively, the classic 'self' or 'that' variable should work too.

```
const self = this
currentBusiness.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    currentBusinessData = snapshot.val()
    self.setState({isLoading: false}) 
});
```

btw, this.setState is a function and it will trigger a re-render.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Sorry, it posted on enter.

Comment: And again. Guess I have to do it all on one line. Tried self but that failed with variable unknown. Then I tried the arrow syntax and it works. Except for the fact that it doesn't auto-trigger the render, but I can get it to work if I do this.state = {isLoading: false} and then use this.forceUpdate afterwards.

Comment: Okay, got self to work as in it doesn't return an error, but the render still doesn't trigger automatically.

Comment: Ah, I had an = in the this.setState. Guess I should just have copy-pasted your answer rather than type it in myself, then I would have worked like a charm the first time - thank you :-)

Comment: I should've made it more explicit when I said this.setState is a function so you don't assign to it. Glad that you've figured it out, I made the same mistake before and it sticks in your memory :)